# Photos in DCIM folder messed up - sometimes file explorer frozen

Tags: samsung, photos

I have a Samsung S8 and I try to access DCIM folder. Once doing so, sometimes the file explorer freezes and sometimes it does not display all the results. Actually I see some old photos on top. If I search for the latest photos I can find by using the photo name, but it seems that the order has been messed up. On the other hand, the gallery shows properly the pictures in the correct order. Do you know why it happens and how it can be fixed?

Comment: By "file explorer" do you mean an app or the Windows Explorer on a PC connected via USB to your phone?